# MVC4 - Model not been passed to controller for action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, controller

I've got two models.

**Model A** for example contains basic get set for atrributes (i.e)

```
[Required] 
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Name = "Comment: ")]
public string Comment { get; set; }

public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
```

**Model two** uses attributes in modal a, i.e

```
public ModelA Deposit { get; set; }
public ModelA Withdrawal { get; set; }
public ModelA Transfer { get; set; }
```

In my View all I am doing is using 3 forms in one page with very similar fields.
For same reason Withdrawal and transfer work with no problems. The code is almost identical in all 3

However when I am doing deposit, the ActionResult in the post is not been passed on the model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SetViewBagAccounts();

    var model = new ModelB {};

    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Deposit()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Deposit(ModelB model)
{ 
    int acct = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Accounts"]);
    var comment = model.Deposit.Comment;// This causes **NullReferenceException**
}
```

The error I am getting in http post is `NullReferenceExcption`.

When I debug, the model being passed to the action method, `Deposit`, is all empty.

BELOW IS A SAMPLE OF THE VIEW

```
@model Login.Models.ModelB

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ATM";
}

<h2>ATM</h2>

<div id="leftpanel" style="position:absolute;left:0;width:33%;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Deposit", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new {})) 
{


    <div>
        <fieldset>            
            <legend>Deposit Money</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Deposit.AccountNumber1)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select Account --")
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Deposit.Amount)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.Deposit,new {style = "width:150px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=>u.Deposit.Amount)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Deposit.Comment)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(u=>u.Deposit.Comment,new {style = "width:250px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=>u.Deposit.Comment)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" style="width:31%;"/>
            <input type="reset" value ="Clear" style="width:31%;"/>

        </fieldset>

    </div>

}


The div for deposit is pretty much copied again for withdrawal and transfer, only changed bit is :
@using (Html.BeginForm("Withdrawal", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
@using (Html.BeginForm("Transfer", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
```

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: Without the view code, there's very little chance of anyone giving a correct solution to your question first time.

Comment: looks like you are beginner in .net mvc. Use additional partial view for you Comment entity, for example